# The Ryder Gambit

Tags: opening, tournament, gambits

I am learning the Ryder Gambit with a book by FM Eric Schiller called The Ryder Gambit Accepted updated in 2011: A Chess Works Publication so I can play it in tournaments. Is it worse than the Danish Gambit? What do chess engines conclude about this opening?

```
[fen ""]

1.d4 d5 2.e4 dxe4 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.f3 exf3 5.Qxf3 Qxd4
```

Comment: You should phrase this in the form of a question that can be answered without opinion, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be quite a lot worse than the Danish. Stockfish Nnue gives around -0.57 at depth 33 for the Danish (after 4.Bc4), while the Ryder has around -2.36 at depth 32 (in the position after 5...Qxd4 6.Be3).

It's true these are just surface level engine evaluations. However, considering the book you're referencing on the Ryder came out in 2011, I highly doubt Stockfish is missing any crucial analysis that book has which would change its mind in any significant way.

Of course, if you're fairly low rated and believe you can trap a lot of the opponents you face, then the opening may be played as a surprise weapon. But objectively it could be considered losing.

Answer (score 1):

If you play in tournaments that are not class limited to very low players  you should expect to lose a lot more than you draw or win if you try those openings.

You can beat beginners with stuff like that but you wont advance far as the good players will clean your clock.